# syslog-ng perl pipe dropping events

Tags: linux, perl, syslog, syslog-ng

I'm trying to pipe syslogs to a perl script via syslog-ng but not all of the syslog entries make it through - maybe 1 in 3 actually happen.

I've looked all over the place and can't find anyone remotely having the problem that I have. It seems so simple but I can't find the answer!

Here's my syslog-ng setup:

```
source s_1 { tcp(port(514)); };

destination d_zen { program("/tmp/zen.pl"); }; 

log { source(s_1); destination(d_zen); };
```

and here's my perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$|=1

my $filename = "/tmp/zen.log";
open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "could not open file '$filename' $!";

while ( <STDIN> ) {

    print $fh <STDIN>."\n";

};
```

any thoughts?

Comment: fyi i've tried flush_lines (1) and it doesn't help. I'm also concurrently logging to other places and logs are happening appropriately, only this destination is spotty.

Comment: Is this possible for you to tell how frequent are logs getting generated ? If logs are frequent then i will suggest using unix domain socket in between. It worked for me very well in my use case.

Comment: It's actually not very frequent, but can come in blocks of 5 at a time. Maybe once every 10 seconds I'll get 1-5 log entries. I'm not sure I understand domain unix sockets totally is this something I would use inside of my perl script or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you please place your code with while loop here. Also i do not think you need any kind of socket to work with. Socket is placed between syslog and perl script so flow is like  `syslog ==> socket ==> perl script`. Rate of logs in your case is not very much.

Comment: No relation with rate limiting in the conf file ?

Comment: @igael - nope,it works with `flush_lines(1)` and `flush_lines(0)` (which is default) just the same. Also, I found no need for `$|=1` either - this is probably because I'm not passing that much data at a time.

Comment: The key was the `$_` variable. I found out that perl in its awesomeness pipes each line in a `<STDIN>` string into `$_` automagically which worked perfectly for my case. Since my `<STDIN>` wasn't coming from a file but a pipe/stream I used `<>` in my while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My while loop wasn't built properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$|=1;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "/tmp/zen.log";
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "could not open file '$filename' $!";

my $my_string;

while( <> ) {
    $my_string .= $_;
    print $fh "$my_string\n";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Perl line buffer disabled?

According to the [syslog-ng manual](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-program.html), it can cause some problems:

"Certain external applications buffer the log messages, which might cause unexpected latency and other problems. For example, if you send the log messages to an external Perl script, Perl uses a line buffer for terminal output and block buffer otherwise. You might want to disable buffering in the external application."

Also, I don't know how your script reads the incoming messages (I don't now perl), but I think it should use a loop to keep reading incoming messages.
So syslog-ng should start the script once at startup, and it should keep running and processing messages.

HTH,

Regards, 
Robert Fekete

Comment: I've tried turning off buffering with `$|=1` also I actually had a `while ( <STDIN> ) { }` loop but no dice! Thanks for the insights.

Comment: Stupid idea, using while ( 1 ) instead of while ( <STDIN> )? (Or something that is always true, to avoid that the script exits)